# Whitespace is lost during MathML -> XMLElement conversion

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion, xml

```
ImportString["<mtext> </mtext>", {"MathML", "XMLElement"} ]
```

> ```
> XMLElement["mtext",{},{}]
> ```

while I'd expect:

> ```
> XMLElement["mtext",{},{" "}]
> ```

It's more than inconvenient because:

```
ExportString[
 XMLElement["mtext", {}, {}],
 "XML"
 ]
```

> ```
> "<mtext />"
> ```

when I need:

```
ExportString[
 XMLElement["mtext", {}, {" "}],
 "XML"
]
```

> ```
> "<mtext> </mtext>"
> ```

Is this expected?

Comment: Have you tried ExportString[ImportString["<mtext> </mtext>", {"MathML", "XMLElement"}, "NormalizeWhitespace" -> False], "XML"]. "NormalizeWhitespace" set to false instead of the default Automatic. The less instructions given at Import or Export the more one gives control to WRI logic for Automatic expectations. Automagic.

Comment: @Hans nice, wasn't aware of that. Please consider posting an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
ExportString[ImportString["<mtext> </mtext>", {"MathML", "XMLElement"}, "NormalizeWhitespace" -> False], "XML"]
```

From XML/tutorial/ImportingXML. I thought the default for "NormalizeWhitespace" was Automatic. However the documentation states that "True" is the default, where "all the whitespace inside an element is normalized (default)".

Comment: I wouldn't say expected due to the fact that `ImportString` ref page contains no info about available options.

Comment: The ref/ImportString page contains a pointer to Import under Details. It would be nicer if WRI just simply reiterated the options under ImportString.

Comment: and where is this option mentioned on Import page? ;)

Comment: It is not. One would have to dig 4 levels into the Tutorial to get this information for "XML" format XML/tutorial/ImportingXML. I just meant  the pointer note in the Details of ImportString "ImportString works just like Import, with the same element specifications and options."  However, the way I got to this information was to type "NormalizeW*" in the Help. Just using prior knowledge of normalizing white space in SGML, XML, HTML with recollection that Mathematica has a "NormalizeWhitespace" option. I actually knew how to use it. But still searched for spelling.